# Virtual Env name not written in terminal when activated

Tags: django, virtualenv, atom-editor

I am using atom text editor and when I am activating my virtual environment the name is not written in the start so while programming I am not aware that the environment is activated or not.

The environments in my library are as following.
[image: Checking environments]

when I activate using command `activate MyDjangoEnv` but the name of the environment is not shown in brackets like it is usually there. I am always confused that the environment is activated or not while installing the libraries.

Following picture explains my issue.
[image: Name of venv not shown in terminal window]

Comment: Check if your environment variable  `VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1`... or you can change it using `export PS1` based on you requirement.

Comment: Did you launch Atom from the command prompt? Some packages require it to do in order to ensure full access to env vars.